# MySql query displays wrong time, but date is right

Tags: mysql, date, time

after a long search I found the script I was looking for. Works fine. But one aspect works wrong: 
date and time.
Normally I should receive

```
5   2014-02-24 14:59:28     7   NULL    
5   2014-02-24 15:32:55     6   -1  
5   2014-03-08 10:32:19     60  54  
5   2014-03-08 10:40:23     20  -40     
5   2014-03-08 10:44:22     21  1   
5   2014-03-08 15:05:54     2   -19     
5   2014-03-08 15:06:10     25  23
```

but I got:

```
5   2014-02-24 02:59:28     7   NULL    NULL
5   2014-02-24 03:32:55     6   -1  -14.2857%
5   2014-03-08 03:05:54     2   -19     -90.4762%
5   2014-03-08 03:06:10     25  23  1150.0000%
5   2014-03-08 10:32:19     60  54  900.0000%
5   2014-03-08 10:40:23     20  -40     -66.6667%
5   2014-03-08 10:44:22     21  1   5.0000%
```

This is just the example for the stock_id 5. Others were wrong with time, too. 
My code is following:

```
select stock_id,date_format(date,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') as date
, price,pxchange,concat(round(pxpct*100,4),'%') pxpct
from (select 
     case when stock_id <> @pxticker then 
         @pxclose := null end,
    p.*,
    (price-@pxclose) as pxchange,
    (price-@pxclose)/@pxclose as pxpct,
    (@pxclose := price),
    (@pxticker := stock_id)
  from quotations p
  cross join
  (  select 
     @pxclose := null,
     @pxticker := stock_id
     from quotations 
     order by stock_id, date limit 1)  as a
  order by stock_id, date ) as b
order by stock_id, date asc
```

But what went wrong? I added (date,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') right, didn't? Anyone with an idea where the problem is?

---

EDIT - ADDITIONAL QUESTION AND CODE

```
SELECT 
stock_id, stocks.name,
date_format( date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) AS date, 
price, 
pxchange, 
concat( round( pxpct *100, 4 ) , '%' ) pxpct, 
stocks.stockmarket, 
stockmarkets.id

FROM (
SELECT
CASE WHEN stock_id <> @pxticker
THEN @pxclose := NULL
END , p . * , 
(price - @pxclose) AS pxchange, 
(price - @pxclose) / @pxclose AS pxpct, 
(@pxclose := price), 
(@pxticker := stock_id)

FROM quotations p

CROSS JOIN 
(
SELECT @pxclose := NULL , @pxticker := stock_id
FROM quotations
ORDER BY stock_id, date
LIMIT 1
) AS a
ORDER BY stock_id, date
) AS b 

LEFT JOIN 
stocks ON stock_id = stocks.id
LEFT JOIN
stockmarkets ON stockmarkets.id = stocks.stockmarket 
WHERE stocks.stockmarket = (SELECT id FROM stockmarkets WHERE short ='NASDAQ')
GROUP BY stock_id
ORDER BY stock_id, MIN(date) ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date function needs an uppercase H for your output to be in 24 hour format, otherwise it will output the AM/PM date, without the AM/PM symbols (i.e. only from hour 0-11).

Comment: Thanks, @Emir. I rate you positive after waiting time is over.
Unbelievable how important one letter can be.

Comment: Yeah, this thing screwed me over a few weeks ago too. Sorting by time doesn't work when you have the wrong dates!

Comment: @Emir or anyone else: do you know why I don't get the youngest entry? I added the code in an edit session and tried in PHPmyAdmin, but I still got the oldest entry. Also tried max(date) asc and max (date) desc and min(date) asc/desc.